# How to display table row data based on headers sequence from json objects in Angular 6?

Tags: html, json, angular, angular5, angular6

I am facing problem in showing dynamic table from JSON objects. I have two array. One array contains headers of the table and other array contains JSON objects.The problem is that I want the data to be shown in sequence of header array value from each JSON Object(each object is treated as row).
The code I have tried to show data is:

```
    <table id="myTable">
    <tr >
    <th *ngFor="let head of FilteredKeys;let i =index" (click)="sortTable(i)">{{head}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let object of finalContactsArray;">

    <td *ngIf="hasProp('FilteredKeys', 'id')">{{object.id}}</td>
    <td *ngIf="hasProp('FilteredKeys', 'firstname')" >{{object.firstname}}</td>
    <td *ngIf="hasProp('FilteredKeys', 'lastname')">{{object.lastname}}</td>
    <td *ngIf="hasProp('FilteredKeys', 'prefix')">{{object.prefix}}</td>

     </tr>
    </table>
```

Filtered Key array is:

```
    ["id","firstname","prefix","lastname"]
```

finalContactArray is:

```
    [{"id":"1","firstname":"Vikas"},{"id":"2","firstname":"Raj","lastname":""},{"id":"3","prefix":"Mr.","lastname":"sdsdfsd"},{"id":"4","prefix":"Mrs."},{"id":"5","firstname":"Hari","prefix":"Mr."}]
```

For demo of the problem the stackblitz is:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8cacgk

Here you can see that prefix column values are shown in lastname.How to get rid of this problem?

My working code:

```
     <table id="myTable">
     <tr >
     <th *ngFor="let head of FilteredKeys;let i =index" (click)="sortTable(i)">{{head}}</th>
     </tr>
     <tr *ngFor="let object of finalContactsArray;">
     <ng-container *ngFor="let head of FilteredKeys">
     <td *ngIf="head==='id' && hasProp('FilteredKeys', 'id')">{{object[head]}}</td>
     </ng-container>
     <ng-container *ngFor="let head of FilteredKeys">
     <td *ngIf=" head === 'prefix' && hasProp('FilteredKeys', 'prefix')" (click)="showalert()" style="cursor:pointer" >{{object[head]}}</td> 
     </ng-container>
     <ng-container *ngFor="let head of FilteredKeys">
     <td *ngIf=" head === 'firstname' && hasProp('FilteredKeys', 'firstname')" >{{object[head]}}</td>
     </ng-container>
     <ng-container *ngFor="let head of FilteredKeys">
     <td *ngIf=" head === 'lastname' && hasProp('FilteredKeys', 'lastname')">{{object[head]}}</td>
     </ng-container>

     </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data structure is this simple and the relationships are that direct, you can accomplish this with simple nested for loops:

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr >
    <th *ngFor="let head of FilteredKeys;let i =index" (click)="sortTable(i)">{{head}}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let object of finalContactsArray;">
    <td *ngFor="let key of FilteredKeys" 
      (click)="key === 'prefix' && showalert()"
      [ngStyle]="{'cursor': (key === 'prefix') ? 'pointer': 'default'}">
      {{object[key] || ' '}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Just iterate through your rows and within rows iterate over your header keys to show the correct row property in the cell, and create cells for every column regardless of what the actual object contains. My example puts in a single space as a placeholder if no value for that column, but you could put whatever you want, all depends what your requirement is, but you need to create cells for every column, regardless of if the object has the property or not, otherwise the cells will never align correctly.

Comment: Your solution works.Just one more thing how can I add a checkbox to each row of the table to get the row data.I am new to Angular and not getting it how to implement it...

Comment: im not sure what you mean by add a checkbox to get the data, try to describe it more or add some code illustrating what you're after

Comment: The solution you provided has one limitation.Suppose I want to add some events like click on only prefix columns cell.How to implement this with ur provided sol.?

Comment: I got the solution but I think it can be made more efficient.I updated my code which is working.

Comment: yea that solution is incredibly inefficient, if you're going to explicitly list of all of the columns anyway, there is no point in iterating over your header list every single time.  As for click handling, the simplest method to me would be to apply a generic click handler that accepts the property value and the key and handles it appropriately based on key.

Comment: I updated my answer to mirror the functionality in yours, but not exactly how i described in my previous comment.  The method in my previous comment would be a bit "cleaner" and more flexible.